# A word for realising the insignificance of human life against the scale of the universe and enjoying it

Tags: single-word-requests

A man sits on a bench considering his woeful burden. He looks up at the stars and compares the distance from here to his house and here to the furthest visible star Deneb. Suddenly his problems seems pitifully faint and untroubling. He laughs and relaxes in his seat, staring at the ducks.

> Look again at that dot. That's here, that's home, that's us. On it everyone you love, everyone you know, everyone you ever heard of, every human being who ever was, lived out their lives. The aggregate of our joy and suffering, thousands of confident religions, ideologies and economic doctrines, every hunter and forager, every hero and coward, every creator and destroyer of civilization, every king and peasant, every young couple in love, every mother and father, hopeful child, inventor and explorer, every teacher of morals, every corrupt politician, every "superstar," every "supreme leader," every saint and sinner in the history of our species lived there—on a mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam.
>   ~Carl Sagan
>
> I really believe that if the political leaders of the world could see their planet from a distance of 100,000 miles their outlook could be fundamentally changed. That all-important border would be invisible, that noisy argument silenced. The tiny globe would continue to turn, serenely ignoring its subdivisions, presenting a unified façade that would cry out for unified understanding, for homogeneous treatment. The earth must become as it appears: blue and white, not capitalist or Communist; blue and white, not rich or poor; blue and white, not envious or envied. ~Michael Collins, astronaut

I'm looking for a noun or verb that describes this positive enlightening experience.

Comment: *Humility*?  [more chars, for the comment police]

Answer (score 5):

Probably the expression [in perspective](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+something+into+perspective) may suggest what you are referring to: (from TFD)

> - within a reasonable view or appraisal. (*Typically: be ~; get something ~; have something ~; put something [into] ~.)

put something into perspective:

> - (idiomatic) To compare with something to give a clearer, more accurate idea.
> - You can put your worries into perspective when you realise how many people in the world are so much worse off than you.

- The man sitting on a bench compares his woes with the immensity of the universe and this new perspective enables him to have a different perception of himself and his life.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is "[epiphany](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Epiphany)": ( from TFD)

> - A sudden manifestation of the essence or meaning of something.
> - A comprehension or perception of reality by means of a sudden intuitive realization: "I experienced an epiphany, a spiritual flash that would change the way I viewed myself" (Frank Maier).

Comment: This answer would be improved by including a definition and the use of the word in a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can call it ***awe*** or ***a moment of awe***, and you are *in awe* of the *awe-inspiring* universe. That's awesome!

> A person who is in awe of a monumental natural wonder, such as a massive mountain peak or waterfall, **may feel insignificant**. Awe is an emotion comparable to wonder but less joyous, and more fearful or respectful. One dictionary definition is "an overwhelming feeling of reverence, admiration, fear, etc., produced by that which is grand, sublime, extremely powerful, or the like: in awe of God; in awe of great political figures".
>
> **In general awe is directed at objects considered to be more powerful than the subject**, such as the breaking of huge waves on the base of a rocky cliff, the thundering roar of a massive waterfall, the Great Pyramid of Giza, the Grand Canyon, or **the vastness of open space in the cosmos.**
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insignificance  (Emphasis mine)

Below is a passage from an article titled "The Power of Awe" that goes in parallel with your example and explains *awe* in detail:

> Imagine you’re standing at the rim of the Grand Canyon with a majestic purple-and-orange sunset blazing across the western sky. You stand transfixed for an hour, then look up at the awesome expanse of stars. You are transformed, lifted, in awe.
>
> B’aima literally means “with awe.” Awe is an experience so powerful that it’s paralyzing. On the other hand, we know awe to be extremely exhilarating. What defines an awesome experience?
>
> When we look at the expanse of stars, we see power, beauty, harmony. We realize that each tiny star is actually a raging sun. And in the face of tremendous force, we feel insignificant by comparison. We realize our own weakness, our smallness, our mortality.
>
> Yet surprisingly, this doesn’t depress us. It inspires us. Because we’re merged with the greater whole. That realization can be a source of tremendous positive energy. And if you know the secret of awe and use it effectively, you can actively release its power in day-to-day living.
>
> http://www.simpletoremember.com/articles/a/the-power-of-awe/

---

A bonus article titled "25 Awe-Inspiring Reminders Of Just How Insignificant We Are:Prepare to feel tiny":

http://myscienceacademy.org/2013/01/07/25-awe-inspiring-reminders-of-just-how-insignificant-we-areprepare-to-feel-tiny/

Answer (score 1):

Sonder:

n. the realization that each random passerby is living a life as vivid and complex as your own—populated with their own ambitions, friends, routines, worries and inherited craziness—an epic story that continues invisibly around you like an anthill sprawling deep underground, with elaborate passageways to thousands of other lives that you’ll never know existed, in which you might appear only once, as an extra sipping coffee in the background, as a blur of traffic passing on the highway, as a lighted window at dusk.

Answer (score 1):

Yugen?
 “an awareness of the universe that triggers emotional responses too deep and mysterious for words.”

—Rheingold, Howard. *They Have a Word for It: A Lighthearted Lexicon of Untranslatable Words and Phrases*. Los Angeles: J.P. Tarcher, 1988. ([Snippet view, pg. 109.](https://books.google.com/books?id=QGBjA5YCMSIC&dq=they%20have%20a%20word%20for%20it&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=yugen))

Comment: Interesting word. But please mention and link to your sources.

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U! I've added a citation for your definition, which I believe is the original source of this particular wording. If you're aware of an earlier source, please change it! If you found the definition somewhere else, you could also add a link to that.