# Name of the sensation you feel when confronted by the immensity of something like the sea or the universe)?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word I'm seeking is a word used to describe the feeling you get when confronted with the immensity of nature and how little we are. It's what you get when you stand on the beach, watching the ocean when a storm is coming, or looking at the stars at night in the open, it's not fear, though it has some of that, it's a lot of mixed emotions: awe, fear, contemplation, admiration, etc.

It's not a word I made up, I read it a long while ago on a grammar group and now I need it, but I can't remember it.

And it's not a common word neither, it's very specific, it's the name of that mixed feelings you get in the situations I described, neither positive nor negative, a mix of both.

Someone mentioned ¨sonder¨ on the comments, and it's quite near that, but sonder means realizing your problems are minuscule compared to the Universe, which is not the same

And I apologize for not being clear enough before, English is not my native tongue.

Comment: Related: "[A word for realising the insignificance of human life against the scale of the universe and enjoying it](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202483)". Is that the kind of word you want, or do you want a word for feeling like a dot compared to the universe and *not* enjoying it? Giving more details about what you want this word to mean, and in what context you want to use it, will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: There are words that describe the experiencing of a grand revelation, some of which are included in the answers to the question @suməlic linked. However, none of these words speak specifically to the realization of the idea this question describes.

Comment: @TomásVittino I'd request that you elaborate to explain if you want a general word for realizations of this magnitude or a specific word for this specific realization.

Comment: _Inconsequential_ springs to mind.

Comment: @suməlic is right -- we need the feeling you're aiming for.  "Overwhelmed"?  The "awestruck" or "in awe" answer is very good -- it's hard to tell where you want to go with this.

Comment: oceanic feeling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_feeling

Comment: I'm reading an article on "inspiration" as a psychological construct, and "vastness" keeps getting used as an emotional characteristic of "awe," but thus far it hasn't been defined. I'm wondering if this is what you're looking for. I wonder if your definition is the definition I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 7):

How about **Awestruck**?

> Filled with or revealing awe: 
>   e.g. people were awestruck by the pictures sent back to earth
>
> [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/awestruck)

from

> **Awe**
>
> > A feeling of reverential respect mixed with fear or wonder:
> >     e.g they gazed in awe at the small mountain of diamonds
> >     the sight filled me with awe
>
> [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/awe)

Answer (score 2):

The adjective "sublime" is the word I use for this.  The OED defines it as:
 "Of a feature of nature or art: that fills the mind with a sense of overwhelming grandeur or irresistible power; that inspires awe, great reverence, or other high emotion, by reason of its beauty, vastness, or grandeur."

Answer (score 1):

Without clarification I'd suggest **feeling [dwarfed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dwarf?q=dwarfed#dwarf__15)**.

> *dwarf VERB* Cause to seem small or insignificant in comparison

Some books use it that way:

> Admittedly this is a highly Romantic text in which Kleist feels himself dwarfed by the immensity encompassed by the painting, and yet his confusion results in more than a glimpse of the sublime.  - [One](https://books.google.de/books?id=EN2gYp92OT0C&pg=PA140&dq=%22dwarfed+by+the+immensity%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu-qr_wO7OAhWMB5oKHcbNA0oQ6AEIWjAI)
>
> I felt dwarfed by the immensity of Lay Me Down's illness. - [Two](https://books.google.de/books?id=gYcRAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT147&dq=%22dwarfed+by+the+immensity%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLiPniwe7OAhXBjCwKHb2wCFQ4ChDoAQgxMAM)
>
> After a moment, when I got used to the dark,I found a light switch and was startled to discover myself dwarfed by the immensity, power, and beauty of Clifford Cole's paintings, which were hanging and standing everywhere. - [Three](https://books.google.de/books?id=OFu2BgAAQBAJ&pg=PT19&dq=%22dwarfed+by+the+immensity%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqyquUwu7OAhWMWCwKHSPLA4M4FBDoAQhYMAg)

Comment: "dwarf" adjective, verb, or noun: - Be careful. It's best to use a synonym, except in established contexts such as "dwarf iris."

Answer (score 0):

I heard the writer and videogame critic Yahtzee refer to this feeling as a

> Perspective-Spiral

referring to the feeling of mounting insignificance as you gaze into the cosmos.

I thought it was quite an evocative term. It more specifically refers to the vertigo-like feeling one can get when looking at the stars, and the ego barrier breakdown that comes with internalizing the vastness of the universe for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Numinous:

A numinous experience is when something completely astonishes you. It’s such an experience that words are not enough to describe the feeling, but it leaves you knowing that there's must be something more powerful than you. Often people refer to things in the natural world that are so beautiful they feel overwhelmed. For example, the view from the top of a mountain or a beautiful sunrise. For others it may be an experience such as a new born baby. For some people this experience is so strong that it convinces them that God must exist.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a phenomenon known as the ‘overview effect’ which has been attributed to the sensation some astronauts experience when looking at the earth. I appreciate it is not one word - but like you, I too had read this ‘word’ somewhere and could not find it - this is as close as I have come and I think it was what I was looking for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think the "Overview Effect" is what you're looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

"Existential crisis" is the phrase I know of.

Comment: You should add some explanation of why you think this fits.

Comment: Crisis? I don't think that fits.